# Changing \thesection (latex) locally

Tags: latex

How may I locally change `\thesection` command?
For example, in all chapters I'd like to have the usual `\thesection`, like
`\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}`, but in a single chapter I'd prefer to have just `\arabic{section}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just set

```
{
\chapter{Here happen strange things}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \section{Without chapter-number}
}
```

By wrapping your modified chapter into braces, the `renewcommand` will only work in this single chapter, not outside of the block.

If needed don't forget to also change the numbering for `subsection` and `subsubsection`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works! I've thought before, \renewcommand can be used outside \begin{document} ... \end{document} only. Quite a surprising thing!